Profile image is not loading in Laravel
I am using this way to get the image url but it is not working. Can anyone help?
<img src="{{ $user->getImageUrl() }}" alt="profile picture">

I am storing the image path in the database like this
profile/xa6OUndH8AoSZ6bL1JbQe1CXM5tedXfoRbMDVgCQ.png

My function in the User model:
function getImageUrl(){
    if($this->image){
        $imagePath = 'public/' . $this->image;
        if(Storage::exists($imagePath)){
            return url('storage/' . $this->image);
        }
    }
    return url('storage/default-user.png');
}

Here is the location of my image:

and the location which is shown on the browser

how to solve this issue

Did you run php artisan storage:link? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

have you set up symlinks in your config\filesystems.php?

Make sure to run php artisan storage:link
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk
Also, you could leave out the url() function and just return a string starting with "storage/". In this case you will have to insert the URL with {!! $user->getImageURL() !!} so it doesn't get html encoded.
If the problem is with the url() function, try making sure the APP_URL is correct in your .env file.


In laravel the file directly uploaded under the storage folder so for
using it you have to run

php artisan storage:link

Check the documentation here Laravel
